# MVC Error redirect doesn't seem to redirect for me in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC 3. I have edited my Web.Release.Config

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now when I get a run time error I am still seeing:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
```

Complete with a link to my SOURCE CODE :-(

Note that when I run I have it set to "Release" and I run with CTRL F5

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this locally? You'll notice that only remote users will be sent to your custom error page.

```
mode="RemoteOnly"
```

To see this working locally too you can set the value to `On`:

```
mode="On"
```

So you're Web.Release.Config will look like:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="On" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hello Jamie. It's still not working. Maybe I need to create a GenericError.htm file?

Comment: I noticed I still have this in my web.config <customErrors mode="On"/>

Comment: Create the GenericError.htm file and let me know how that goes.